# Find most dominant local minima

Tags: c++

Currently, the below code finds all local minima, but I am interested in finding the most dominant/(strongest peak) in a 1D array. I was wondering if anyone could assist me with it?

```
for(int v = 1; v < width; v++) {
if (data[v] > data[v - 1] && data[v] > data[v + 1] )
    ml.push_back(v);
}
```

Comment: What does that mean to you? Global minimum? Most negative derivative? You need to define what "strongest" means mathematically before trying to write it in code.

Comment: I would like to filter some of the extrema

Comment: You did not answer my question. What does "strongest peak" mean?

Comment: the current code gives me all local minima. I am interested in the strongest local minima, but not the gobal minima

Comment: Does strongest peak is biggest `2 * data[v] - data[v - 1] - data[v + 1]` ?

Comment: You have to define "strongest local minimum" or "strongest peak." Or no one can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if what you want is to save the position of the best (minimum) value or the value itself, but the following code will do both, being `vector` an element of class `sdt::vector<double>`:

```
size_t position(0); double value(vector[0]);
for (size_t i(1), N(vector.size()); i < N; ++i) {
  if (vector[i] < value) {position = i; value = vector[i]; }
}
```

Anyway, I would like to recommend you the Numerical Recipes text book, which is a reference text in scientific computing (http://www2.units.it/ipl/students_area/imm2/files/Numerical_Recipes.pdf). There you can find a full chapter of maximization or minimization of functions.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the feedback. I wonder if by finding just local solutions what he is looking for are heuristic methods... maybe?